# find what is written in a button a user clicks on jquery

Tags: jquery

I am curious how you would find what is written in a div that a user clicks on, and then write an if, else if, else statement to run different blocks of code according to what they clicked on, for exapmple, if this is your html code...

```
<html>
  <div>
    hello world!
  </div>

  <div>
    what's going on?
  </div>

  <div>
    goodbye world!
  </div>
</html>
```

how would you make an if, else if, else statement to run different blocks of code depending on if the user clicked on "hello world!", "what's going on?", "goodbye world!"?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').click(function(){
     console.log($(this).text());
});
```

But I would have bound an attribute:

```
<div data-context="a" />
```

And check against this attribute because text may be changed in further development.

```
$(this).data('context');
```

Comment: You need to trim the text.

Comment: Definitely, forgive me.

Answer (score 0):

Set an event listener for the `div` elements, and grab the contents after the click.  Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(div).click(function() {
        var contents = $(this).text().trim();
        if(contents=="hello world!") {
          // do stuff
        }
        else if(contents=="goodbye world!") {
          // do stuff
        }
        else {
           // do stuff
        }
    });
});
```

While the above will work, it will also fire on any `div` that is clicked.  A cleaner solution would be an `id` for each `div`, with a listener that fires on their clicks.

The HTML:

```
<div id="first">Hello World!</div>
<div id="second">Goodbye World!</div>
<div id="third">What's going on?</div>
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#first").click(function() {
        console.log($(this).text().trim());
    });
    $("#second").click(function() {
        console.log($(this).text().trim());
    });
    $("#third").click(function() {
        console.log($(this).text().trim());
    });
});
```

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/jbymt/).

Since `div` elements are not usually used as buttons, you should add `role="button"` to each of the `div` elements to make it more accessible to those using screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to have conditions tested based on huge phrases.

Instead have a class for each div and write up your condition based on the class.

**HTML**

```
<div class="one">hello world!</div>
<div class="two">what's going on?</div>
<div class="three">goodbye world!</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('div').click(function() {
   var $this = $(this),
       contents = $this.text();
    if($this.hasClass('one')) {
      // do something   
    } else if ($this.hasClass('two')) {
       // something else   
    }
    ..
    ..
});
```

To get the text inside the element you can just use `text` method

```
$(element).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

```
$(document).on('click', 'div', function (){
   var test = $(this).text().trim();
   if(test  == "hello world!"){
    alert("hello");
   }
    else{
        alert("Something else");
    }
    //the rest of the condition
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/CUuuU/)

Comment: because the text is not trimmed

Answer (score 0):

See this example:

```
$("div").click(function(){
   var text = $(this).text().trim();
    if(text == "what's going on?"){
       alert("Option 1");
    }else if(text == "goodbye world!"){
        alert("option2");
    }
});
```

One important element of this example is that the retrieved text is trimmed, this eliminates the whitespace that may be contained within the element.

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/bqn58/